# Is there any iPhone open source community?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, open-source

I am going to develop on iPhone platform and I think the best way to learn is to read good apps' source.

Is there any open source iPhone app community? Like sourceforege or googlecode?

Thanks in advance~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no central repository of iPhone open source code (with the exception of Apple's examples), but there are a few questions here which point out many individual projects (including [mine](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules)):

- ["Are there any Open-source iPhone applications around?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200850/are-there-any-open-source-iphone-applications-around)
- ["Are there any Open-source iPhone games around?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365947/are-there-any-open-source-iphone-games-around)
- ["Open source iPhone components? Reusable views, controllers, buttons, table cells, etc?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640805/open-source-iphone-components-reusable-views-controllers-buttons-table-cells)
- ["What open source Cocoa/Cocoa Touch Frameworks are out there?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501981/what-open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-frameworks-are-out-there)

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of [iphone repos on Github](http://github.com/search?q=iphone&type=Repositories&x=0&y=0). Not all of those are actual apps for the iphone, but enough of them are that that is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked at apple's sample code?

[Here are the repositories on github](http://github.com/search?q=iphone&type=Repositories&x=0&y=0).

Comment: I will take a look at it soon, thank you very mcuh~